# CDi in Vaadin is not injecting: NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, vaadin, cdi, inject

I'm new in Vaadin and I'm trying to inject a `@UIScoped`-bean in my UI-class. But it throws every time a `NullPointerException` - why?

Here is my UI-class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.cdi.CDIUI;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Theme("tableuitheme")
@CDIUI("")
public class Table extends UI {

    private final static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(Table.class); 

    @Inject
    private SomeBean bean;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {



        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        setContent(layout);

        logger.info("-------------------------- "+bean); 

//      String art = hakan.toString();

        Label label = new Label("Hakan");

        layout.addComponents(label);

    }

}
```

And here is the interface `SomeBean` :

```
public interface SomeBean {
}
```

and the implementation class `SomeBeanImpl`:

```
import com.vaadin.cdi.UIScoped;

@UIScoped
public class SomeBeanimpl implements SomeBean {

}
```

And finally my configuration files:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myVaadinUIServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>UI</param-name>
            <param-value>de.ragms.ui.Table</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
        <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myVaadinUIServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

bean.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Comment: Need more info to help. What server are you using? From where the Table bean is used (code, EL, other)? What is the stack trace?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I think the problem comes with the web.xml. First of all if Your using the vaadin-cdi addon the application will use the VaadinCDIServlet and in Your web.xml thers the default VaadinServlet. When using the addon You don't need the web.xml file try to delete it and see if it works.